# Excel 365 fill handle when connected to a source

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-transfer

I am using Excel RTD from FX Blue Labs to connect my Excel 365 (Desktop) to MT4 to get real-time forex data and historical ones.

I need to know how to use the fill handle to fill all the cells without typing the formula in each row.

An example:
After connecting MT4 to Excel, I type this formula 
=RTD("fxbluelabs.excelrtd", ,"Account Number", "@bh,GBPUSD,H4,close,0") to get the current close of GBPUSD H4.

If I change the last number (0) to (1), I will get the previous close.

If I type the formula as =RTD("fxbluelabs.excelrtd", ,"Account Number", "@bh,GBPUSD,H4,close,200") I will get the close of the 200th bar.

Now, the problem is that when I selected the first three or four cells (in a column) with the above formulas and try to use the fill handle, I get the new rows filled the same as the selected row cells.
For ex: 
the columns I have 
col 1         column2
1st            (formula typed) 1.23
2nd            (formula typed )1.34
3rd              (formula typed) 1.22

If I drag the first column, it is filled in the right order with 4th, 5th, 6th etc..

But the column with the formulas that are linked to MT4 is not being filled correctly. Excel just repeats the values of those three rows in the second column.

Any solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The function of Fill Handle in Excel is limited, sometimes filling works well, and other times it doesn't work as you expect. You can check the cell reference of the cells.